# Grid search for tuning my ANN using KerasClassifier wrapper stuck at Epoch 1/1

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to train a simple NN with 1 hidden layer for binary classification. Tried to use GridSeachCV to get best parameters but training won't go beyond first Epoch.

Not getting any values for `best_parameters = gridSearchCV.best_params_` and
`best_accurcy = gridSearchCV.best_score_`
after it stops.

## Code

```py
def build_classifier_grid(optimizer):
    classifier_grid = Sequential()
    classifier_grid.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform',activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier_grid.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform',activation = 'relu'))
    classifier_grid.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, init = 'uniform',activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier_grid.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier_grid

classifier_grid = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier_grid)

parameters = {'batch_size': [25,32], 
              'nb_epoch' : [100, 500],
              'optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop']}

gridSearchCV = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier_grid, 
                            param_grid = parameters, 
                            scoring = 'accuracy', 
                            cv = 10)

gridSearchCV = gridSearchCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Getting like:

```
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 5s 676us/step - loss: 0.5647 - acc: 0.7961
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 5s 681us/step - loss: 0.5626 - acc: 0.7950
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 5s 684us/step - loss: 0.5523 - acc: 0.7956
"
"
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 10s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6167 - acc: 0.7929
Epoch 1/1
8000/8000 [==============================] - 11s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5504 - acc: 0.7959
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not stuck at all, it is just training each model for only one epoch, which is the default value. The problem is that you use the parameter `nb_epoch`, and the correct name in Keras 2.x is `epochs`.

Comment: So happy that worked. Thanks!! Just wondering how it worked before, I used it in couple of other places but didn't get this issue.

Comment: @Shamika You probably had Keras < 2.0 in those other places.